# Using Eloquent to retrieve data shows different array

Tags: sql, eloquent, laravel-5

Well I am very very new to Laravel. So I am learning the basics from Laracast actually. I have a table called songs , a model `Song.php` as below:

```
<?php namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Song extends Eloquent{

}
```

And a Controller `SongsController.php` :

```
use App\Song;
use DB;

class SongsController extends Controller
{
    function index() {
        $songs      = Song::get(); 
        $songs2     = DB::table('songs')->get();dd($songs2);
        //$mysong2    = Song::whereSlug('as-long-as-you-love-me')->first(); 
    }
}
```

So I expect `$songs` and `$songs2` are same and produce same result. but `dd($songs)` produce result something like below:

```
Collection {#146 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Song {#147 ▼
      #connection: null
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:6 [▼
        "id" => "1"
        "title" => "As Long as you Love me"
        "slug" => "as-long-as-you-love-me"
        "lyrics" => null
        "created_at" => "2015-06-21 00:00:00"
        "updated_at" => "2015-06-21 00:00:00"
      ]
      #original: array:6 [▶]
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
    }
  ]
}
```

and `$songs2` produces ( which I think the actual,but not sure):

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#145 ▼
    +"id": "1"
    +"title": "As Long as you Love me"
    +"slug": "as-long-as-you-love-me"
    +"lyrics": null
    +"created_at": "2015-06-21 00:00:00"
    +"updated_at": "2015-06-21 00:00:00"
  }
]
```

So I want to know which one should I use ? And is there any mistake I am doing ?

Answer (score 0):

there is no mistake.
for $songs you are using eloquent with function **get()**, which will always return an object of type
*Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection* 
but for $songs2  you are using **query builder** with function **get()**, which will always return an array of 
***stdClass*** objects.

thats why you see different results.
both are correct and you can use both, but if you have created a model for your song, then use eloquent instead of query builder.